# Embedd <label> into DataTable based on ajax json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

```
var table = jQuery('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
dom: 'Bfrtip',
lengthMenu: [
    [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
    [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
],
ajax: {
  url: 'getClients.php',
  dataSrc: 'aaData',
  method:'POST'
},
columns: [
  { data:'client_name'},
  { data:'client_location'},
  { data:'client_region'},
  { data:'client_remarks'},
  { data:'client_status'}
],
select: true
});
```

The above javascript is used to fill a DataTable. My Requirement is ,i need to add <label> tag into DataTable row cell based on client_status value.
if client_status value is 0 then i need a type label ,if it is 1 i need to add another label.

is it possible to add html into datatable at the time of table filling via ajax json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table = jQuery('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
     lengthMenu: [
                    [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
                    [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
                 ],
     ajax: {
          url: 'getClients.php',
          dataSrc: 'aaData',
          method:'POST'
     },
     columns: [
          { data:'client_name'},
          { data:'client_location'},
          { data:'client_region'},
          { data:'client_remarks'},
          { data:'client_status',render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
               if (data == 'N' ){
                   return '<label  class="bs-label bg-blue">New</label>';
               }else if (data =='O'){
                   return '<label  class="bs-label bg-green">On Board</label>';
               }else if (data=='I'){
                   return '<label  class="bs-label bg-red">In-Active</label>';   
               }}
           }
      ],
      select: true
 });
```

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Comment: from getClient.php we get a json data. client_status having values like N,O,I .  Before rendering dataTables its check the values is equals to N or O or I . if its matches return the HTML what i passed here.